# Eureka+Cloud-Config with Wildfly and deployment order

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config

I need to integrate some SpringBoot services in a Wildfly environment. 
There is a Eureka-Server+Cloud Config-Service runing as a WAR in a wildfly. I cannot see the dashboard, but I can see the self-registered service in the XML data in ..eureka/apps
If I start a SpringBoot client for Eureka/Cloud Config in a standalone mode - it connects perfectly to this Wildfly/Eureka/CloudConfig service. The same, when I add this client as a WAR into the already running Wildfly/Eureka/CloudConfig system.

But when I kill the server and restart it, the parallel deployment of the two WARs produce of course a lot of exception during startup. Thats ok, because the Eureka Server isn't up yet. But after it's - the client registeres itself correctly to the Eureka server (I see it in eureka/apps again). But the client sends exceptions all the time.

```
2018-06-22 12:40:10,345 WARN  [org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration] (DiscoveryClient-CacheRefreshExecutor-0) Could not locate configserver via discovery: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instances found of configserver (EUREKA-DISCOVERY-SERVICE)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerInstanceProvider.getConfigServerInstance(ConfigServerInstanceProvider.java:25)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.refresh(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:80)
        at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.heartbeat(DiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration.java:72)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor122.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:261)
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:180)
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:142)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:406)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354)
        at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.onCacheRefreshed(CloudEurekaClient.java:112)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:981)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1471)
        at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1438)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The exception comes every 30sec (refresh time).
I don't understand, why this happens. The ...eureka/apps result shows the service

```
<applications>
  <versions__delta>1</versions__delta>
  <apps__hashcode>UP_2_</apps__hashcode>
  <application>
    <name>EUREKA-DISCOVERY-SERVICE</name>
    <instance>
      <instanceId>192.168.207.94:eureka-discovery-service:8443</instanceId>
      <hostName>localhost</hostName>
      <app>EUREKA-DISCOVERY-SERVICE</app>
      <ipAddr>192.168.207.94</ipAddr>
      <status>UP</status>
      <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
      <port enabled="false">80</port>
      <securePort enabled="true">8443</securePort>
      <countryId>1</countryId>
      <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
        <name>MyOwn</name>
      </dataCenterInfo>
      <leaseInfo>
        <renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
        <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
        <registrationTimestamp>1529662231729</registrationTimestamp>
        <lastRenewalTimestamp>1529663993904</lastRenewalTimestamp>
        <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
        <serviceUpTimestamp>1529662210687</serviceUpTimestamp>
      </leaseInfo>
      <metadata>
        <management.port>8443</management.port>
        <configPath>/eureka-ds/config</configPath>
      </metadata>
      <homePageUrl>http://localhost:80/</homePageUrl>
      <statusPageUrl>http://localhost:8443/actuator/info</statusPageUrl>
      <healthCheckUrl>http://localhost:8443/actuator/health</healthCheckUrl>
      <secureHealthCheckUrl>https://localhost:8443/actuator/health</secureHealthCheckUrl>
      <vipAddress>eureka-discovery-service</vipAddress>
      <secureVipAddress>eureka-discovery-service</secureVipAddress>
      <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>true</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
      <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1529662231729</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
      <lastDirtyTimestamp>1529662193289</lastDirtyTimestamp>
      <actionType>ADDED</actionType>
    </instance>
  </application>
  <application>
    <name>MARK2</name>
    <instance>
      <instanceId>192.168.207.94:mark2:9998</instanceId>
      <hostName>192.168.207.94</hostName>
      <app>MARK2</app>
      <ipAddr>192.168.207.94</ipAddr>
      <status>UP</status>
      <overriddenstatus>UNKNOWN</overriddenstatus>
      <port enabled="true">9998</port>
      <securePort enabled="false">443</securePort>
      <countryId>1</countryId>
      <dataCenterInfo class="com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo$DefaultDataCenterInfo">
        <name>MyOwn</name>
      </dataCenterInfo>
      <leaseInfo>
        <renewalIntervalInSecs>30</renewalIntervalInSecs>
        <durationInSecs>90</durationInSecs>
        <registrationTimestamp>1529662210686</registrationTimestamp>
        <lastRenewalTimestamp>1529663979339</lastRenewalTimestamp>
        <evictionTimestamp>0</evictionTimestamp>
        <serviceUpTimestamp>1529662210687</serviceUpTimestamp>
      </leaseInfo>
      <metadata>
        <management.port>9998</management.port>
        <configPath>/eureka-ds/config</configPath>
        <user>user</user>
        <password>software1</password>
      </metadata>
      <homePageUrl>http://192.168.207.94:9998/</homePageUrl>
      <statusPageUrl>http://192.168.207.94:9998/actuator/info</statusPageUrl>
      <healthCheckUrl>http://192.168.207.94:9998/actuator/health</healthCheckUrl>
      <vipAddress>mark2</vipAddress>
      <secureVipAddress>mark2</secureVipAddress>
      <isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>false</isCoordinatingDiscoveryServer>
      <lastUpdatedTimestamp>1529662210687</lastUpdatedTimestamp>
      <lastDirtyTimestamp>1529662208806</lastDirtyTimestamp>
      <actionType>ADDED</actionType>
    </instance>
  </application>
</applications>
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer may be helpful for the error **`No instances found of configserver(configserver)`**,

Spring Cloud Config Server has the default name as "configserver" If you override this name using the `spring.application.name=my-config-server` in `application.properties` then in the Config Client application's `bootstrap.properties` you need to use `spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=my-config-server`

Sample Config Server

```properties
spring.application.name=my-config-server
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:////Users/asadhat/work/lab/spring-cloud
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Sample Config Client

```properties
spring.application.name=my-config-client
server.port=7000
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
spring.cloud.config.discovery.service-id=my-config-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, to get it work.

- If I set spring.cloud.config.fail-fast=false (which is the default) then the service makes multiple retries. Then during bootstrap the service sends errors, but after the config server is up, the client service registeres and everything is ok. That takes some seconds...
- then - I learned, do not put Eureka server and Cloud config server in one service. Even it is a good idea to reduce the minimize the infrastructure, the cloud config service is a little bit triggy and needs full access to the URL path. Even defining prefixe doesn't really work because of a minor bug (there is a pull request).
- third - in a Wildfly environment define the StatusPageURLPath and HealthCheckURLPath correctly (see above, it's wrong)